# Cannot parse string variable with dynamically created JSON code in Jquery to be decoded and read in PHP

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, variables, dynamic

I've created a script in jQuery that 
1. automatically grabs specific values from elements that are dynamically created on the page by the user
2. prepares these values into a query format for an insert by mysql 
3. formats into JSON format to be send to php script via ajax where we will manipulate these JSON objects and perform the insert of these values into the mysql database.

This is what I can't seem to figure out --

When I manually set a variable string in javascript with the intended JSON format using test values, the values are sucessfully sent php script via ajax and the values are successfully inserted into the database.

However, when I try to dynamically construct my string variable using the values from the dynamic content on the page, the php script throws an error :

'Trying to get property of non-object'

Error is being thrown at the 'foreach' loop in the php script where the '$theArray->questions' syntax is being used.

Which is weird because when I use the 'alert' function in jquery using both methods (manually setting JSON and dynamically constructing the JSON, I get EXACTLY the same output. Also, when I set manually I am able to use the $.parseJSON function but when I use dynamic method using this function breaks the script so when I try dynamically I have to comment out this function.

I suspect something funky is happening in the background of these variable based on the way I am assigning the values (manually and dynamically using a variable). Here is pertinent code :

---

### JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY)

```
//Manually create JSON string to send to php to insert values into mysql db
//var questionsquestion = '{"questions":[{"question":"test16","type":"radio", "html":"<input>"},{"question":"test2","type":"checkbox", "html":"<input>"},{"question":"test3","type":"checkbox", "html":"<input>"}]}';
//questionsquestion = $.parseJSON(questionsquestion);

//set arrays
var questionstype = [];
var questionshtml = [];
var questionsquestion = [];

//Store all 'questions', 'question types', and 'html' for each fieldset into 3 separate arrays
for(var i=1;i<=formpreviewid;i++)
{
 questionsquestion.push($("#formelement_"+i + " legend").text());
 questionstype.push($("#formelement_"+i).attr("class"));
 questionshtml.push($("#formelement_"+i)[0].outerHTML);
};

//format values for each fieldset into values format for mysql
var questionsvalues = [];
var index = 0;
for(var i=1;i<=formpreviewid;i++)
{ 
questionsvalues.push('{"question":"'+questionsquestion[index]+'","type":"'+questionstype[index]+'","html":"'+questionshtml[index]+'"}');
index++;
};

//dynamically format mysql values into JSON format
var questionsvaluesjson = '{"questions":['+questionsvalues+']}';

//questionsvaluesjson = $.parseJSON(questionsvaluesjson);

var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(questionsvaluesjson);

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/project/templates/yoo_nano2/php/saveform.php',
data: {'formpreviewhtml': formpreviewhtml, 'jsonArray': jsonArray},
beforeSend:function(){
// this is where we append a loading image
$("#formpreview").append('<div style="z-index:3000;" id="divoverlaycontainer"><div id="loaderoverlay"><div class="center" id="loader"><img src="/project/templates/yoo_nano2/images/loader.gif"></div></div></div>');
}, success:function(data){
alert(data + "Saved form successfully.");
//$('#viewresults').empty();
$('#divoverlaycontainer').remove();
// successful request; do something with the data
//$('#viewresults').html(data);
}, error:function(){
// failed request; give feedback to user
alert("Save was unsuccessful. Please try again.");
$('#divoverlaycontainer').remove();
}
});
});
});
```

### PHP

```
<?php 
//create object/array from json data
$theArray = json_decode($_POST['jsonArray']);

//connect to database
require_once('connect.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
//set query to drop table           
$query = "DROP TABLE registrationquestions;";
//execute the query
$mysqli->query($query);
//set query to create table 
$query = "CREATE TABLE registrationquestions(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
question TEXT,
type CHAR(255) ,
html TEXT)";
//execute the query
$mysqli->query($query);
//insert new questions

$insert = "";

foreach ($theArray->questions as $data)
{   
  $insert .= '("' . $data->question . '", "' . $data->type . '", "' . $data->html . '")';
}
$insert = str_replace(")(","),(",$insert);

$query = "INSERT INTO registrationquestions (question, type, html) VALUES " . $insert; 
$mysqli->query($query);
    ?>
```

Comment: You can just send an array with jQuery's `$.ajax`, and catch it in PHP, there's no need for all the JSON conversion stuff here ?

Comment: Can you annotate your code to show exactly where the error is thrown?

Comment: Hey Gibberish -- I've added more information about where error is being thrown in the question as per your suggestion : Error is being thrown at the 'foreach' loop in the php script where the '$theArray->questions' syntax is being used.

Comment: That's a new one on me... do you get a similar error if you use `$theArray['questions'] as $data` instead?

Comment: Ross -- just tried your suggestion and get 2 different errors on same line : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in, Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Is there anything wrong with calling an array variable into a string? -- var questionsvaluesjson = '{"questions":['+questionsvalues+']}'; .. I feel like this is where the problem might be because I can't use $.parseJSON on questionsvaluejson, but I can use $.parseJSON on the manually created variable 'questionsquestion'

Comment: On top of putting `$theArray['questions']` in your foreach - try adding `true` into your json_decode:  `json_decode($_POST['jsonArray'], true)` to ensure you're getting an associative array out of it.

Comment: Get the same errors with or without the 'true' parameter in json_decode($_POST['jsonArray'], true) : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in, Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .. I've been wrestling with this roadblock for 3 days now AGHH!!!

Comment: Well, if it's not parsing that out then there is perhaps something wrong with the JSON being passed in.  Try `var_dump($_POST['jsonArray'])` and putting it through [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).  If that doesn't work, try recreating a jsFiddle if you can stand the frustration!  Good luck!

Comment: you are right -- the HTML code I was passing had double quotes which I presume was breaking it -- when I remove the questionshtml variable from the JSON string it inserts the data successfully.. now I just need to figure out how to get the HTML part to work, for some reason $.parseJSON doesn't work on it.. thanks for your help!